# How to determine if subscriber is opted in for API triggered email

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, ampscript

We are configuring a triggered send in our ET account that will be deployed via an external API. We want to determine if the subscriber is still opted in before we send. How is this possible?

Comment: Are you calling standard or custom webservices? If you are calling custom webservices, you have more options ...

Comment: We are using a standard web service.

Comment: mass email or single email?

Comment: Opted into what?  All Subscribers?  A List?  A Publication?

Comment: Singel email and opted in to All Subs table. Think we found the solution here: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_subscribers_by_subscriber_key/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve a users status using their subscriber key. Found here: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_subscribers_by_subscriber_key/